# selecting a gridview row and changing the color of that row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview, I want the row of the gridview to be turned blue when the user clicks on the row and turned to the original color if the user chooses to click on another row. so for .e,g

```
Col1   Col2

1       Test1
2       Test2
```

if the user clicks on row1 then row 1 shoud be blue, but if the user chooses to click on row2 then Row1 should come back to its original color and row2 becomes blue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As default it sets the cell at which you click to blue. So to get entire row blue, there's an  easy way do this:

Click on your gridview and go to its properties on the right side of the screen. There will be a *Selection Mode* property of gridView set it to ***FullRowSelect***.

Answer (score 0):

I is in the SelectedRowStyle BackColor. You can set the color of the selected row there. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add `SelectedRowStyle` property to your `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">      
     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Blue" />  Add this in your Gridview markup
        <Columns>  
          //
        </Columns>          
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the value of the first column of that row and put that value in the textbox along with the row color changing.